# Is there a coredump_filter for core dumps on OS X

Tags: macos, coredump

We use the file

```
/proc/self/coredump_filter
```

to control the type of data when a process core dumps on Linux. Is there an equivalent filter to use for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Dumping core is uncommon on Mac OS, and is not enabled for any signals by default. By default, all crashes which occur outside a debugger are handled by "Crash Reporter", which writes a report to `Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (either in the user's home directory, or in the global domain for system processes). Depending on the system configuration, it may also display a "… quit unexpectedly" dialog to the user.

Comment: You can enable core dump using `ulimit -c unlimited`